# how can i connect my table to another table in asp.vb?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Sorry if this seems simple. Either I'm not asking the right question, or understanding the answers I've found so far.

i need to join columns
(Ex. `tbl_lockers` has `Employee` and `tbl_employee` has `Name` column)

I  need to join the same data from `tbl_employee`.`Name` to `tbl_lockers`.`Employee`
 Any thoughts? Thanks.

I'm a newbie in `SQL`.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: try some tutorials as refer in the above comment

Comment: Google T-SQL or Transact SQL (the SQL Server variant of SQL). There are tons of tutorials on this and Microsoft has hundreds if not thousands of pages of documentation online. A join is a very basic feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
SELECT * FROM 
tbl_employee, tbl_lockers
WHERE tbl_employee.Name = tbl_lockers.Employee
```

Specifing the exact columns may be needed if both tables contain columns with the same names.

Answer (score 0):

To show **all employees who have a locker** (ie. all criteria match), do this...

```
SELECT e.*, l.*
FROM tbl_employee e
    INNER JOIN tbl_lockers l ON l.Employee = e.Name
```

To show **all employees whether they have a locker or not**, change the JOIN Criteria to...

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_lockers l ON l.Employee = e.Name
```

To show **all lockers whether they have a employee or not**, change JOIN Criteria to...

```
RIGHT JOIN tbl_lockers l ON l.Employee = e.Name
```